# Intent throwing error in click listener in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Hi guys I am trying to change screens from my MainActivity class to my UserLogin class inside a click listener, here is my code.

```
package com.example.user.appproject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog progressDoalog;
    EditText firstname, lastname, age,email;
    Button insert, show;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String insertUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/insertRecord.php";
    String showUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/showStudents.php";
    TextView result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFirstname);
        lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLastname);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAge);
        insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
        email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        System.out.println(response.toString());
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        parameters.put("firstname",firstname.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("lastname",lastname.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("email",email.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("age",age.getText().toString());

                        return parameters;
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(request);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserLogin.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        });

    }

}
```

However, i am getting an error saying

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.user.appproject, PID: 20311
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.appproject/com.example.user.appproject.UserLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.user.appproject.UserLogin.onCreate(UserLogin.java:65)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I don't understand where the null object reference could be as if I take out the intent code everything works fine, My userLogin class is defined in the manifest file as such.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".UserLogin"/>
</application>
```

Here is the xml code for the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="firstname"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtFirstname"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="lastname"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtLastname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtFirstname"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtLastname"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="age"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="INSERT STUDENT"
        android:id="@+id/insert"
        android:layout_marginBottom="138dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help will be much appreciated

main code for UserLogin:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UserLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Creating EditText.
    EditText Email, Password;

    // Creating button;
    Button LoginButton;

    // Creating Volley RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    // Create string variable to hold the EditText Value.
    String EmailHolder, PasswordHolder;

    // Creating Progress dialog.
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    // Storing server url into String variable.
    String HttpUrl = "https://192.168.1.11/userLogin.php";

    Boolean CheckEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Assigning ID's to EditText.
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Email);

        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Password);

        // Assigning ID's to Button.
        LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

        // Creating Volley newRequestQueue .
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UserLogin.this);

        // Assigning Activity this to progress dialog.
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserLogin.this);

        // Adding click listener to button.
        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if (CheckEditText) {

                    UserLogin();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });

    }

    // Creating user login function.
    public void UserLogin() {

        // Showing progress dialog at user registration time.
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.show();

        // Creating string request with post method.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                        // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        // Matching server responce message to our text.
                        if(ServerResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")) {

                            // If response matched then show the toast.
                            Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Logged In Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            // Finish the current Login activity.
                            finish();


                        }
                        else {

                            // Showing Echo Response Message Coming From Server.
                            Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                        // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                        Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                // Creating Map String Params.
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // Adding All values to Params.
                // The firs argument should be same sa your MySQL database table columns.
                params.put("User_Email", EmailHolder);
                params.put("User_Password", PasswordHolder);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Creating RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UserLogin.this);

        // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot() {

        // Getting values from EditText.
        EmailHolder = Email.getText().toString().trim();
        PasswordHolder = Password.getText().toString().trim();

        // Checking whether EditText value is empty or not.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(PasswordHolder)) {

            // If any of EditText is empty then set variable value as False.
            CheckEditText = false;

        } else {

            // If any of EditText is filled then set variable value as True.
            CheckEditText = true;
        }
    }
}
```

XML code for UserLogin screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    tools:context="com.example.user.appproject.UserLogin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Volley User Login System"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Your Email"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/editText_Email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Your Password"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/editText_Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Email"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLICK HERE TO LOGIN"
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText_Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hello are you there , share your xml layout code , so i can help you

Comment: i have just edited the XML code into my original question :)

Comment: ok give me few mins let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are setting wrong layout in your UserLogin Activity.

You are setting activity_main.xml instead you need to set your UserLogin Activity layout XML file .

You are doing like this

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Instead you need to do like

`setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_USER_LOGIN_ACTIVITY_LAYOUT);`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have moved my intent to outside the signature with no avail, even putting it in the oncreate function still throws the same error. It doesent seem to want to go

Comment: I have just tried this and it throws the same error

Comment: hi charlie , use like this it will fix your problem

Comment: hello, thank you for that but I need all the code to run as a whole, nothing seems to work, even if i add the intent in the same spot you put it in with all my other code with it

Comment: there is no error with button reference actually as i tested , now error seems with something else , maybe either your response doesnt come or some error with volley

Comment: I have tested all the code without the intent code, and it all works fine and inserts the data I input into my PHP file. it only gives an error when I try to intent to another screen

Comment: can you post the code of your second activity java and xml both

Comment: I got it and updated answer pls check bro and accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

You used your main_activity.xml inside of your login activity code. Use the correct layout and you will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Thunder and Sam. Both of your answers worked, I simply changed the content view in my UserLogin class to correlate with the XML view for that class instead of the main activity. I thought it automatically put the correct content view when the activity is first created but whatever. Thank you so much guys!

Comment: hello! I just upvoted it, but due to my reputation not being good on here my upvote gets recorded but doesn't change the publicly displayed score post on this page, but it does give you an upvote! Thanks again for your help, it was much appreciated

Comment: Sorry i am kinda new to this, i just accepted it now anyway :)